# NearbySearch results differ from SearchBox

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

So I have been using the nearbysearch and searchbox combined because I noticed searchbox doesn't have a pagination function and nearbysearch has it. One this I noticed is that the results are not close to being similar. What I mean is that the number of results don't always come out to be 20 when we have searchbox as 20, the nearbySearch only produces like 18.

Is there a reason for this? I have done a plunker for some advise on how to solve this. In the console you can see that the bounds are set to the map.

```
 var request = {
      bounds: map.getBounds(),
      keyword: input.value
 };
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IcLSQxmTjMQ4jFsqc7da?p=preview

**EDIT** If we type in pizza as the search box we can see that there are 20 results from the searchbox and only 7 searches from the nearbySearch.

[image]

Comment: It is returning 20 results every time i search for something, first time i search for restaurant it gave me 20 results, 2nd time i searched bar and it gave me 20 results, 3rd time i searched for taxi service and it gave me 20 results, let me show you the result in picture

Comment: Check update below

Answer (score 0):

------------------------------------------------------------- **UPDATE** ---------------------------------------------------------

Its still 20

[image]

It is returning 20 results every time i search for something, first time i search for restaurant it gave me 20 results, 2nd time i searched bar and it gave me 20 results, 3rd time i searched for taxi service and it gave me 20 results, let me show you the result in picture

[image]

Comment: I have updated the plunker. What I had done was zoomed in a bit more and have shown the case of the difference in the arrays.

Comment: Sorry no. I was just updating to show that the searchbox shows 20 results while the nearby shows 7 results updated in the plunker example